# Vulkan validation error for each objects when destroying device, despite their destruction

Tags: validation, destructor, exit, vulkan

In an android native application, when I call:

```
vkDestroyDevice( vk.device, VK_ALLOCATOR )
```

I've got error Error:    *[Validation] Code 614466292 X object 0xffffffffd3bcb900 has not been destroyed (...).*

But I have called vkDestroy(Object) for each of the objects. (image, imageview, pipeline, etc)

Here is one object creation / destruction:

```
static void create_shader_module(const unsigned char* pBytes, const int count, VkShaderModule* pVkShaderMod) {
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo desc;
    desc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    desc.pNext = NULL;
    desc.flags = 0;
    desc.codeSize = count;
    desc.pCode = (const uint32_t*)pBytes;          
    VK(vkCreateShaderModule(vk.device, &desc, NULL, pVkShaderMod));
}
extern unsigned char multiview_single_texture_vert_spv[];
extern int multiview_single_texture_vert_spv_size;
create_shader_module(multiview_single_texture_vert_spv, multiview_single_texture_vert_spv_size, &s_gShaderModules.single_texture_vs);
```

And for the destruction part:

```
vkDestroyShaderModule(vk.device, s_gShaderModules.single_texture_vs, NULL);
```

When I call vkDestroyShaderModule, vk.device is still active, and I 've got no error.
But as soon as I call vkDestroyDevice(), I've got error:

> OBJ ERROR : For device 0xeb0ac330, ShaderModule object
>   0xffffffffeb0c6240 has not been destroyed. The spec valid usage text
>   states 'All child objects created on device must have been destroyed
>   prior to destroying device'

Freeing the struct memory with   memset(&s_gShaderModules, 0, sizeof(s_gShaderModules));  does not solve the problem.

The error is on an android device, unfortunaly I can't test the application on another device.
Everything else in the application works, I even destruct and recreate some of the objects at runtime without error, except the application crash on exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just removed the validation layers, and surprisingly the application no longer crashes, the closing sequence ends successfully. Why didn't I try it earlier?
The problem only occurs with layers, it may be due to their order in the extension array.